# What happens to units and buildings if they get "buried" under destructible rocks?

Tags: starcraft-2

HOTS introduces the new "destructible rocks" that can actually be destroyed, as the name suggests. One part of rocks crushes down and blocks a predefined area.

What happens to units and buildings standing on that spot while the rocks get destroyed?

Comment: Heart of the Swarm doesn't even come out for several months; is there a public beta or something?

Comment: Well there are pre order beta keys available in most countries.

Comment: After dicussing this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6982257#6982257), we've determined that the threshold for unreleased games is that it has to be publicly available.  To that end, I've voted to close this.

Comment: They are pushed out of the way, or if they can't be moved, they die. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BA6cl0_UzqY

Comment: I thought this question was closed?

Comment: @Ender see http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are pushed out of the way, or if they can't do so, due to fungal, hold position units, etc., they die. See:

Comment: I have followed the link and it seems that the rocks cause 500 damage, which kills every unit and damages most buildings without destroying them. I am not certain if armor negates some of the damage, so perhaps an Ultralisk could barely survive that with all upgrades.

Comment: @ayckoster Possible. Armor doesn't reduce any other triggered/spell damage in the game, however, so it would be unlikely. I also don't believe you could place buildings in areas where this would matter.

Comment: There is a popular HOTS map that has destructible rocks at the 3rd so that the rocks fall exactly at the optimal expansion placement (where you would place your nexus or hatch). I cannot remember the name, I can look it up later.